# Update an array using a text field value that a user enters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on a rails application (version: 2.3.8) ruby version 1.8.7 and I have table which lists all the records for a particular class 
example

### View

```
<h2> purifications in last <%= text_field_tag "number", @n %> days </h2>

<div class="purifications"> 
 <table>
    <%@purifications.each do |r|%>
     <tr>
       <td><%= @purification.name %></td>
     </tr>
    <%end%>
 </table>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
def purifications
    @n = 30
    @purifications = Purification.find(:all, :conditions => ["end_date > ?", @person.id, @n.days.ago.to_s(:db)])
end
```

I want a way to update this using Jquery or javascript and ajax using a remote method.
 Could someone help me on how to go about doing this?

I have tried using

### View

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script> 
  $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    $j(document).ready(function(){
     $j("number").change(function update_table(){
        $j.post("/protein_purification/remote_test",
          {
          number_for_update: $('this').value,
          });
        }); 
     });


</script>
```

### controller

```
def remote_test
    raise params.inspect
end
```

I am not able to pass any params at all,
The console is not giving any errors too.
I could not figure out how this works because I am new to ajax.
Is there any Easier way to go about this, I am working on rails 2.3.8
Anyone? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your selector:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
 $j("number").change(function update_table(){
   # ^ Here, it is trying to find a HTML element <number></number>
```

You should use this selector instead:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
 $j("#number").change(function update_table(){
   # ^ this will try to find any html element matching id 'number'
```

Also, Im not sure but I think you cant define a function in a callback like this, try this instead:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
 $j("#number").change(function () {
    $j.post("/protein_purification/remote_test",
      {
        number_for_update: $('this').value,
      });
    }); 
 });
```

Or the equivalent:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j("#number").change( update_table($(this).val()) );
});

window.update_table = function (value) {
    $j.post("/protein_purification/remote_test",
      { number_for_update: value });
    });      
    # this function is clearly unfinished
}
```

Comment: Hi Yoshiji, The selector wont work for me because the element I am trying to find using jquery is the <input> element which is of type 'text' and which holds the value as the number inside the tag. I tried $("number") as well I am not able to select it

Comment: It will obviously not work as Im saying from the start! Try `$j('input#number')` to find an input with html id 'number'